# How to get the values from Dropdown listbox and textfield ,then send it that values to webservices?

Tags: javascript, xml, jsp, textfield, html-select

In this Code i try to get the value from text-field and dropdown listbox , I get values dynamically from user and send that value to webserices, In Given code get the value pass that values to webservice through javascript, but script didn't reponse to that code.. any one help me to fix this problem.

```
Here Code:
     <body style=" "><script type="text/JavaScript" >
      var xmlhttpuserid;
        functionmyFunction()  {
            var checkid=new Array();
            var userid = document.getElementById("userid").value;
            for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
            {
             if(document.getElementById('domainid'+i).checked==true)
             {
               checkid[i]=document.getElementById('domainid'+i).value;
               alert(checkid); 
             }
            }
         // var domainid = document.getElementById("").value;
        //alert(userid);
        var url= "../webservice/Passwordstation/ws_userauthpwdstation.jsp?  userid="+userid+"&domain="+checkid;

    alert(url);
        xmlhttpduserid=GetXmlHttpObject();
        if (xmlhttpduserid==null)
        {
          alert ("Your browser does not support Ajax HTTP");
          return;
        }

        xmlhttpduserid.onreadystatechange=getuserid;
        xmlhttpduserid.open("GET",url,true);
        xmlhttpduserid.send(null);   
}

        function GetXmlHttpObject()
           {
            //alert("GetXmlHttpObject1");
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
             {
               return new XMLHttpRequest();

             }
             if (window.ActiveXObject)
             {
                return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }
             return null;

           }

           function getuserid()
            {
              if (xmlhttpduserid.readyState==4)
              {
                var text=xmlhttpduserid.responseText;
                 //alert(text);
                 text=text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
            // alert("Text 2"+text);
                   if(text.match("SUCCESS"))
                    {
                       alert("Authenticate successfully");
                       window.location="accountmain.jsp";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      alert("Please check your User id");
                    }
                }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

I   hope this will help you .

You can get them in java script and pass them in the query as  query parameter as already doing for user id .

```
// var domainid = document.getElementById("").value;
        //alert(userid);
var textboxval = document.getElamentById("mytextbox").value;
var dropDown = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
var dropDownValue= dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;

        var url= "../webservice/Passwordstation/ws_userauthpwdstation.jsp?  userid="+userid+"&domain="+checkid&textboxvalue="+textboxval&selectedFromDropDown="+dropDownValue;
```